# Стоит ли проверять на null и кидать NullReferenceException при работе с необнуляемыми ссылочными типами?

Tags: c#, .net, null

В C# с версии 8.0 появилось понятие NRT (обнуляемые ссылочные типы). Это позволяет "сказать" компилятору о том что все ссылочные типы, кроме специально помеченых знаком '?', **НЕ** должны  допускать `null`. Однако, насколько я понимаю, это работает лишь на уровне предупреждений и ничто не мешает сделать так:

```
#nullable enable
string notNullText = null; // с предупреждением, но скомпилируется
```

Учитывая вышесказанное возникает вопрос, которые я совмещу с кодом:

```
#nullable enable

public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(string parameter)
    {
        // тут parameter считается не нулевым, однако, как я уже показал в предыдущем примере, он всё же может быть null
        // Вопрос: стоит ли тут писать if (parameter is null) throw new ArgumentNullException()
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть аналогичный вопрос на [инглише](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54526652/when-to-null-check-arguments-with-nullable-reference-types-enabled). Как отмечено там в коментах, тут наверно надо ориентироваться на то что является ли вызывающий код покрты фичей `#nullable`. Если нет или не известно, то проверка не повредит.

Comment: спасибо за ссылку)

Comment: Эта штука является лишь предупреждением для вас, которое показывает о том, что в данной строке может вернуться null, в плане работы c# кода, по сути, изменений нету, а это значит, что даже если вам кучу всего подсветит, то вы всеравно будете ловить NullReferenceException там, где обращаетесь к null объекту. Нужна вам там проверка - делайте. Не нужна, ибо уверены, что там не будет null - не делайте, пометьте переменную так `string notNullText = null!;`, заглушит вывод предупреждения. Не хотите получать null - сделайте изначально не null значение, например `string notNullText = string.Empty;`.